Can a toilet paper holder be mounted to the side of a fiberglass tub?
The tub wall has sufficient width to ensure the screws will not penetrate the interior wall.  What precautions must be taken to ensure the drilled holes do not crack?

They would need a bit force applied to crack.  I would be more worried about keeping the paper dry on the side of a tub.

You won't crack the tub unless you go ape with your tools. A small bit spun quickly with light force will make a clean hole. If you need a hole larger than about 1/4", start with a smaller bit and expand from there.
That said, I really don't like putting permanent holes in expensive fixtures. Consider other options such as high quality double-sided tape or a freestanding holder.
If you find that the wall of the tub at your location is too thin to hold a screw firmly, consider expanding anchors such as these. They effectively clamp to the tub skin and become reusable. Be sure to find the right length for your application or they won't work.

image source

Double sided tape is an excellent solution here.  3M command strips are easily removable too, which has value.

Those are good anchors
but you have to choose the right one
They work based on wall thickness
The Neck shows it for what wall thickness are they made for

